# Schematic Symbol Help Possible Antiquated JFET Symbol Conversion

Tags: schematics, jfet, drawing

This is an old schematic, and the MPF102 JFET in the picture is confusing me.

Can someone help me identify the Gate, Source, & Drain connections to this symbol, please!

My guess is that the bottom right pin is gate, but it is not intuitive for me.

Here is the old symbol, from the schematic:

[image]

Since the MPF102 is no longer available, I chose to replace it with a J113, and here is how I typically see it drawn:

[image]

Would someone be willing to map the equivilent pins of both of these two symbols so I can see whats going on.

Comment: What difference do you expect between drain and source? And yes, the gate is the terminal that is 'alone'.

Comment: In many cases with today's JFET's the drain and source are interchangeable.

Comment: drain and source are indeed almost interchangeble, thats why the drain is shown right in the middle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen a JFET be symbolized as such, honestly. But I did look on Google for images of this MPF102 JFET and this is what I found.
[image]

As you can see, the symbol matches the second JFET symbol for the J113 JFET. I believe the confusion that you're having is that these transistors will look differently on a schematic, which is not true. However, I believe that the symbol that you're seeing with the MPF102 is different because it's either an older schematic or that's how the software defines how JFETs look.

In terms of particular JFET devices, they will all look the same on a schematic diagram with the exception of the component name on the schematic (assuming that the doped channel is the same, N-Channel, P-Channel, etc.). The pinout of the transistor is going to be the same as well. In other words, with respect to schematic diagrams, the MPF102 and J113 will look the same and will have the same pinouts.

Comment: Thank you Duken for your comment.  I agree 100% with everything you have presented.  Do you have a suggestion for how to connect this JFET given the information provided?  This schematic is from 1998, while its not quite an antique, my guess is that it was drawn in the wild west days of computer aided circuit design.

Comment: I would presume that the diagram for the MPF102 that you have shown is relatively the same. The bottom left side being the gate, the bottom right (with the arrow pointing out) being the source, and the top right being the drain. It would be interesting to see the rest of the schematic to really confirm my suspicion.

Comment: Duken, The full schematic may be seen at this address:  http://www.raptorzone.co.za/images/noise_canceller_schematic_diagram.gif  AND thank you again for the help, I now feel that the gate is bottom left as well.

Comment: My suspicion is correct :) looking at the surrounding BJT devices, I can now assume that the orientation of this JFET is similar to the BJTs in the circuit. (be sure to click on that check mark and give a +1 if you find people's answers as helpful to what you're looking for)

Comment: The data sheet says: *n-channel depletion* , but, of course, a  JFET is always a depletion type. With MOSFET you can have depletion and enhancement types.

Answer (score 0):

The first symbol is indeed quite old.

Quoting from my old electronics course book *Grondslagen van de electronica 2* (Basics of electronics), by J. Davidse, 1975, who worked at Philips Nat Lab, and was professor at what is now Technical University Delft (Netherlands):

[image: quote text]

*there is not yet a uniform usage of schematic symbols, see Fig 8.16 and 8.17*

[image: schematic symbols]

Encircled are the three options for n-channel JFET.

In the same book series, in Vol. 1, page 33, he explains that the arrow points at the direction for the charged particles in the channel. In the n-channel, the particles are electrons, like in vacuum tubes. In the p-channel, the moving particles are holes, which are positively charged.

Although symbol (a) survived, with the arrow in the gate, just note that actually the gate does not really carry a current, which may be the reason that Davidse used throughout the book rather symbol (c). Davidse / Philips were perhaps "right", but, as we know, Philips does not really do world-class research in electronics anymore.

Note also that for MOSFET, today the arrow is in the substrate. Hence, an n-channel JFET and n-channel MOSFET show the arrows in *opposite directions* :-)

About symbol (j), without any arrow, the text on page 182 says:

*This is a generic symbol that does not tell you which type it is. It is used for schematics with lots of similar components (usually p-channel).*

In the entire book series: g=gate, s=source, d=drain.